# Fast loading Admob ads in activity

Tags: android, admob, ads, banner-ads

I have my android app in play store but the problem I am seeing is that even though the admob ads load within the activity, even on good internet / wifi connection speed, it takes a lot of time (around 4-5 secs) for the 1st ad to get loaded on activity.

I have implemented the ads in the similar way as shown here (except that all the admob properties like adunitid etc are put in xml rather than in code) - https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

but the ads take longer to load. I have seen many apps, wherein even the banner ads load super fast.

Is there a way to achieve that, as I feel, by the time, the ads load in my app, the user would be going on to the next screen, thereby never getting a chance to click on the ad.

Answer (score 1):

That is about the same speed it takes for my first add to load, and then subsequent ads are faster.  I would try to relocate your ads to a place in your application that is more static - meaning, if your users are going to be swiping through layouts, don't place the ads in a layout that the users will immediately leave.